# How can I send a video from my app to Instagram Stories?

Tags: android

I try to share a video from my application to Instagram Stories or Feed but it is run for the Feed not run for the stories. Why the same code successfully runs for the Feed, not for the stories.

**My Sharing Codes:**

```
protected void shareInsta()
{
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(dest));
     sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
     sharingIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
     sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Video ")); 
 }
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

Comment: I already do this but it doesnt work because when I try to Uri.parse(filePath); it does not convert to uri :(

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it may help you**

```
public static void shareVideo(Activity activity, String sharedImgPath, String pkgName) {

        ArrayList<Uri> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(sharedImgPath.replace("file://", "").trim())));

        Intent intentImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentImage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intentImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(sharedImgPath.replace("file://", "").trim())));
        intentImage.setType("video/*");

        if (pkgName.length() > 0) {
            intentImage.setPackage(pkgName);
        }
        activity.startActivity(intentImage);
    }
```

**How to call**

```
shareVideo(context,"file://storage/abc/video.mp4","com.instagram.android");
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference

Comment: are you passing valid context?

Comment: if you are  calling funtion from Activity then pass this, if you are calling function from fragment then pass getActivity().

Comment: Check you BuildConfig import. it should come from you package name. 
suppose you package name is com.abc.xyz the import should come from import com.abc.xyz.BuildConfig;

Comment: Thanks but I do everything but it does not work.Thanks again